# Codeigniter SimpleSAML stuck on Consent page

Tags: php, codeigniter, saml, simplesamlphp

I am trying to implement saml for my website via simplesamlphp. I am using SSOCircle as an IDP and when I test using the simplesaml admin page, I am able to retrieve the user data properly.

However, when trying to integrate it to my login page, and when I try to verify my user, they are stuck on an endless loop on the consent page. I have tried checking my metadata but if my admin page can verify it properly I am unsure of why the api method fails.

This is my code

```
public function index()
    {
        $sp_auth = 'default-sp';
        $as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple($sp_auth);
        $as->requireAuth(array("ReturnTo"=>BASE_URL,"KeepPost"=>false));
        $attributes = $as->getAttributes();
        print_r($attributes);

//        $data['languages']= get_all_languages();
//        $this->load->view('layout/users/login/header',$data);
//        $this->load->view('layout/users/login/errors');
//      $this->load->view('login',$data);
//        $this->load->view('layout/users/login/footer');
    }
```

$as->requireAuth is supposed to redirect the user to the SSOCircle login page then redirect back to mywebsite. However at the moment I can't seem to return.

The BASE_URL variable is my website login url which is www.site.com/app

UPDATE: I just checked the logs and I have received this warning

```
Mar 12 23:26:26 simplesamlphp WARNING [da20d4a7a3] Could not load state specified by InResponseTo: NOSTATE Processing response as unsolicited.
```

I was told that this is because of lost state information. However I have checked my cookie names and they match up. What else have I missed?

https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/wiki/State-Information-Lost

Comment: be sure to include the whole path in your BASE_URL-variable, including http or https: `http://www.example.com/app`

Comment: Hi @MichaelK, I did. my BASE_URL variable is https://www.example.com/app

Comment: If you load the ```session``` library before you call ```$as->requireAuth()```, that will cause an endless redirect loop. Remove ```'session'``` from ```config/autoload.php``` if you find it there. Also make sure ```MY_Controller/__construct()``` does not load anything that loads the session library.